# Pandas Flatten a dataframe to a single column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have dataset in the following format:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3], 'y':[10,20,30], 'v1':[3,2,3] , 'v2':[13,25,31] })

>> v1 v2  x   y
   3  13  1  10
   2  25  2  20
   3  31  3  30
```

Setting the index column with x, I  want to flatten the data combining v1 and v2 (V), The expected output is like:

```
>> x   y   V
   1  10   3
   1  10   13
   2  20   2
   2  20   25
   3  30   3
   3  30   31
```

And again bringing to the original format of df. I tried reshaping using stack and unstack, but I couldn't get it the way, which I was expecting.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html). Last [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) column `level_2`:

```
print (df.set_index(['x','y']).stack().reset_index(name='V').drop('level_2', axis=1))
   x   y   V
0  1  10   3
1  1  10  13
2  2  20   2
3  2  20  25
4  3  30   3
5  3  30  31
```

Another solution with [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) and [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
print (pd.melt(df, id_vars=['x','y'], value_name='V')
         .drop('variable', axis=1)
         .sort_values('x'))

   x   y   V
0  1  10   3
3  1  10  13
1  2  20   2
4  2  20  25
2  3  30   3
5  3  30  31
```

Comment: Thanks for your post, It really helped me out :) But how do you get back the original df , ie v1 and v2 back. Sorry, I am a beginner in python basically.

Comment: Why is `variable` special?

Comment: @jtlz2 - It return `v1, v2`, here not neccesary

Answer (score 5):

`pd.lreshape` can reformat wide data to long format:

```
In [55]: pd.lreshape(df, {'V':['v1', 'v2']})
Out[57]: 
   x   y   V
0  1  10   3
1  2  20   2
2  3  30   3
3  1  10  13
4  2  20  25
5  3  30  31
```

`lreshape` is an undocumented "experimental" feature. To learn more about `lreshape` see `help(pd.lreshape)`.

---

If you need reversible operations, use jezrael's `pd.melt` solution to go from wide to long format, and use `pivot_table` to go from long to wide format:

```
In [72]: melted = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['x', 'y'], value_name='V'); melted
Out[72]: 
   x   y variable   V
0  1  10       v1   3
1  2  20       v1   2
2  3  30       v1   3
3  1  10       v2  13
4  2  20       v2  25
5  3  30       v2  31

In [74]: df2 = melted.pivot_table(index=['x','y'], columns=['variable'], values='V').reset_index(); df2
Out[74]: 
variable  x   y  v1  v2
0         1  10   3  13
1         2  20   2  25
2         3  30   3  31
```

Notice that you must hang on to the `variable` column if you wish to return to `df2`. Also keep in mind that it is more efficient to simply retain a reference to `df` than to *recompute* it using `melted` and `pivot_table`.

Comment: my favorite function ;)

Comment: Thanks for your post, It really helped me out :) But how do you get back the original df , ie v1 and v2 back. Sorry, I am a beginner in python basically.

Comment: I went with `pd.lreshape()` - and hoping it's not still experimental...